# php select multiple checkboxes

Tags: php

i have this code, which helps me to retrieve all table fields and associate a check button to them, but this code is generating the same name, i mean it shows me all the fields, but named the same... id

I need their particulatr name..

can you please see what's wrong?

Thanks..

```
        <form action='report.php' method='post'>

<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_up', $db);

echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hostess");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

// show headers
echo '<thead><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field); // instead of $i
    echo '<th><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $field_name . ']" value="1"/> ' . $field_name . '</label></th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
        $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field);
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) {
            echo '<td>' . $data[$field_name] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';


?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of the mysql_field_name function isn't defined so I am pretty sure PHP is assuming you mean 0 and is returning the first fieldname only. Use the variable you defined ($field) as the index.

Should be:

```
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field); // instead of $i
    echo '<th><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $field_name . ']" value="1"/> ' . $field_name . '</label></th>';
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks,, this was obvious, thanks :)
Can i please ask you help about one thing, once i select the values, how can  display only the selected values? i mean i need to print the fields which i selected, the information isnide them..

Comment: You already do that but you have the same issue in that block of code as what I answered. If you fixed that, and granted you have the form submitting to this script correctly, it should display only the checked ones. Should be: for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
        $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field); // not $i again
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) {
            echo '<td>' . $data[$field_name] . '</td>';
        }
    }

Comment: so i should put inside the report.php this code you just told me?

Comment: Please,s orry for the questions, but is this first part ok? i mean the checking and all stuff? should i proceed with the submission of the form?

Comment: I am not entirely sure which file your code is in but you should just correct the remaining place that you have this: $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $i); and replace that $i with $field.

Comment: can you please tell me then, just give me a hint, how am i supposed to create a table based on the rows i've selected...

Comment: Alright I am going to try to answer what I think the real issue is now. When you build a form you would do what you already do above but you would leave out checking if the checkboxes are set because at this point no one has filled out the form. So build your form as you do above. You would then add the checking and result displaying code in the report.php file because that is where you are telling the form to submit stuff to. So the if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) { .. } stuff would go there. Any further detail wouldn't fit in a comment field. Perhaps create a new question.

Comment: Yes please, i am creating a new question, i'll put there the code, and what i need, please wait until i create the question and i'll pass you the link.. thanks so much..

Comment: here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084701/retrieve-information-from-checkboxes-php-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You are using [mysql_field_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php) and it always return the same name for you(for column 0), because `$i` is not defined.

Comment: Can you please see my updated code? can you help me now with printing all tables , based on the fields i've selected, something like 
Select $checkbox, $checkbox2 etc ...