# Retrieve information from checkboxes php/mysql

Tags: php

i have this code from which i print table rows and a checkbox with them, i need to print the checked rows in another php file.. how am i supposed to do that?

i need something like sql=select $checkbox1, checkbox2 or however it's better to do this....

```
<form action='report.php' method='post'>

<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_up', $db);

echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hostess");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

// show headers
echo '<thead><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field); // instead of $i
    echo '<th><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $field_name . ']" value="1"/> ' . $field_name . '</label></th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
        $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field);
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) {
            echo '<td>' . $data[$field_name] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';


?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Umm... submit the form, retrieve the values of the checkboxes from $_POST, use those IDs to retrieve the info about those checkboxes, print out the info, ... and done?

Comment: i haven't tried anything... because i don't know where to start with this, there isnt anything alike..i've searched on the web..

Comment: Yes, that's all i need to do Marc B

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So first you should only have this file generate the form. Based on the way you laid out the table, you want to have 2 rows with the first being the field names and the 2nd containing the checkboxes themselves. So here's that:

```
<form action='report.php' method='post'>
<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_up', $db);

echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hostess");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

// show headers
echo '<thead><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field);
    echo '<th>'. $field_name . '</th>'; // only the field name
}    
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field);
    echo 
        '<td>
             <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox['.$field_name.']" value="1"/>
        </td>';
}
echo '</tr></tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Then in the file that you are submitting your form to (report.php) you will catch the stuff you posted and display a new table showing only the checkboxes you submitted. Here's an example of what you could do.

```
<?php
// within report.php (THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ONLY)

// check if the checkbox fields were submitted
// and if not empty we know that items have been checked.
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
  // iterate through the checked items.
  // this is an associative array because you gave the items a key
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $field => $value){
    // do some stuff
    echo "<p>Checked Field: $field<br/>Value:$value</br></p>";
  }
} else {
  // display a message saying that nothing was submitted
  // you could also display some error or redirect back to the form etc.
  echo '<p>No Check boxes have been checked</p>';
}?>
```

I hope that this is sufficient to get the ball rolling for you. Try it out, run your code and see how it behaves. Make sure your form is displaying the way you want and that the submit runs correctly and at least shows you something. If needed just use my example code and if you see something it means it reached there. Then you can replace that example code with what you really want to display. Anymore than this and I would essentially be writing your code for you. Give it a shot. Good Luck.